# Weird phenomenon with the perfect squares of numbers under 14.

Tags: square-numbers

In math class (algebra 1), a classmate of mine realized this weird thing when asked the square or 21. In her head, knowing that $12^2$ = 144, she said 12 flipped is 21 so 144 flipped is 441, which is, in fact $21^2$. This doesn't work once you go past 14.

More examples
 (0)$1^2$ = (00)1 and $10^2$ = 100
 $13^2$ = 169 and $31^2$ = 961

Why does this happen? Why doesn't it happen above 14? Are there other places this might work?

Comment: This just works for (some) small numbers because there is no carrying involved.  It also works for longer numbers, like $112, 211$ or even $1112, 2111$ where no carrying is involved.

Comment: Just a random comment: this was one of the first observations I made as a kid that got me into learning basic number theory! It's a great field.

Comment: I think you meant $441$ where you wrote $442$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are squaring $10a+b$ vs. $10b+a$, and the squares are $100a^2+10\cdot2ab+b^2$ vs. $100b^2+10\cdot2ab+a^2$.

If $a^2$ and $b^2$ are a single digit ($0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2$) as well as $2ab$ (hence not $2\cdot3$), the swap works.

Answer (score 0):

Any number only consisting of digits 0, 1, 2 & 3 and the sum of its first n digits being less than or equal to *2 + n* will posses this property.

For example 23021, this number will not posses this property because the sum of the first 2 digits is 5 which is greater then 2 + 2 here *n = 2*

And the number 22021 will posses this property as it follows all the condition

For numbers ending with 0 like 2020

2020 ==> 0202

2020² = 4080400

The square of 0202 must be considered as 0040804